# Counting all elements in map of string to list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is there a better way to calculate  size of all lists in map? So `firstList.size() + secondList.size()`?
I have done this, but creating a list just for counting doesn't feel right approach ..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
    firstList.add("first");
    List<String> secondList = new ArrayList<>();
    secondList.add("second");

    Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put("one", firstList);
    myMap.put("two", secondList);

    int size = myMap.entrySet().stream()
                               .map(entry -> entry.getValue())
                               .flatMap(list -> list.stream())
                               .collect(Collectors.toList())
                               .size();
    System.out.println("Size of all elements in map is:" + size);
}
```

Comment: Let me get this right. You want to get size of all lists in map? So firstList.size() + secondList().size in this example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is at least more readable

```
int size = myMap.values().stream()
     .mapToInt(Collection::size)
     .sum();
```

or if you want to look like a functional programming guru, use:

```
int size2 = myMap.values().stream()
     .reduce(0, (acc, val) -> acc + val.size(), Integer::sum);
```

EDIT: using the `.values()`
:]

Comment: Close, but why bother with Map.Entry objects at all?  Why not just `myMap.values().stream().mapToInt(Collection::size).sum()`?

Comment: `if you want to look like a functional programming guru` - ROFL

Answer (score 3):

Both of the previous answers are good, but can be shortened a bit more by going straight for the `values()`, rather than iterating the `entrySet()`:

```
// Streaming version
int size = myMap.values().stream()
     .mapToInt(list -> list.size())
     .sum();

// Standard loop version
int size = 0;
for (List<String> list : myMap.values())
    size += list.size();
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way:

```
private static int size = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
    firstList.add("first");
    List<String> secondList = new ArrayList<>();
    secondList.add("second");

    Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put("one", firstList);
    myMap.put("two", secondList);

    myMap.values().forEach(value -> {size += value.size();});
    System.out.println("Size of all elements in map is:" + size); 
}
```